# How to set http_headers on celery tasks calls via http

Tags: http, celery, django-celery, celery-task, djcelery

I want to make a task call via HTTP using the class HttpDispatch from celery, but i need to set Authorization header. How can i do this?

```
from celery.task.http import HttpDispatch
request = HttpDispatch(
     url='http://example.com/multiply',
     method='GET', {10})
request.dispatch()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to subclass `HttpDispatch` and reimplement `http_headers` property method. This property is used inside `HttpDispatch`.

```
class CustomHttpDispatch(HttpDispatch):

@property
def http_headers(self):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': self.user_agent,
        'Authorization': 'XXX'}

    return headers
```